# codigo para array y sumar un campo

Tags: javascript

estoy ideando un codigo que me cuente la cantidad de veces que sale un pais en un arreglo, sume la "ProduccionBarriles" y muestre solo los dos que tienen mayor la suma de la produccion de barriles, aca el arreglo:

```
datos = [{ "pais": "EEUU", "ProduccionBarriles": 5200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 8200 },
{ "pais": "EEUU", "ProduccionBarriles": 9200 },
{ "pais": "Mexico", "ProduccionBarriles": 3200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 4200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 8200 }
];
```

La salida que busco seria algo como [{"pais": "EEUU", "salio":2, "sumaBarriles":14400}, {"pais":"Rusia", "salio":2, "sumaBarriles":12400}]...

aca el codigo pero no entiendo porque no me cuenta el ultimo registro, lo suma pero no lo cuenta:

```
var datos = [{ "pais": "EEUU", "ProduccionBarriles": 5200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 8200 },
{ "pais": "EEUU", "ProduccionBarriles": 9200 },
{ "pais": "Mexico", "ProduccionBarriles": 3200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 4200 },
{ "pais": "Rusia", "ProduccionBarriles": 8200 }
];

var res = datos.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  //
  var existItem = acc.find((item) => item.pais === obj.pais);

  if (existItem) {
    existItem.ProduccionBarriles += obj.ProduccionBarriles;
    obj.contador = (obj.contador||1)+1
    existItem.contador = obj.contador
    return acc;
  }

  

  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(res);
```

alguna orientación?

Comment: Usa un bucle para recorrer los arreglos: `for (let i=0;i<datos.lenght;i++){alert("Pais: "+datos[i]["pais"]+"\nProduccion de barriles: "+datos[i]["produccionBarriles"]);}alert("Cantidad de paises: "+datos.lenght);`.

Comment: Que has tratado de hacer? Podrías incluir tu código?

Comment: alli lago del codigo y gracias

Answer (score 1):

De entrada, será necesario que utilices un bucle para recorrer el arreglo. En cada iteración puedes ir guardando el nombre de cada país en un objeto en donde el país será el atributo y la cifra el valor. Luego, en cada iteración vas comprobando si el nombre en la iteración actual [ya se encuentra](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) [en el objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Si no está, lo añades junto con la cifra, y si ya está, solo sumas la cifra. Finalmente, [puedes ordenar el objeto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29622653/3689977) y luego [extraes los dos primeros elementos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195659/3689977). Como veo que los necesitas dentro de un arreglo, solo [los añades](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score -1):

Cambiar

```
obj.contador = (obj.contador||1)+1
```

por

```
existItem.contador+=1
```

y listo.

Les dejo el código por si a alguien le hace falta.